Blank page is displayed instead of the Vite React, and an error in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
I have created a fitness-related react app with Vite and wanted to host it on GitHub pages. Luckily, I managed to host the react app as my very first react app hosted on GitHub, the issue is when I try accessing the react app that I made in any browser I get a blank page, a white empty page with nothing of my thousand lines of code appearing...
The only thing I noticed is an error in the console that says:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () "index-DfpUVyAv.css:1"
This exact error is repeated in the console, I don't know what file is "index-DfpUVyAv.css:1" nor where it is.
https://shlcomp.github.io/youFitnessApp/
I checked the folder's name and it did not have any special characters that might cause the issue.
I added a base to my vite.config.js which is the repository name:
// vite.config.js:

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "/youfitnessApp/",
})


I made sure that my package.json has all the vital lines of code for deploying:
//package.json
{
  "homepage": "https://SHLcomp.github.io/youFitnessApp",
  "name": "fitness",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.2",
    "sass": "^1.79.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^9.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.9",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.1"
  }
}

I used the "CreateBrowserRouter" from react router dom, I think this information could be helpful, as I saw on youtube solutions for the same issue but with people who used react router and routes, the solution was to add a basename to the router and set it to be the value of the base in the vite.config.js, but it did'nt work.
// App.jsx
const router = createBrowserRouter([
// all my objects path and elements are here
]);
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Provider basename="/youfitnessApp/">
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
    </>
  )
};

export default App;

I tried with and without the basename thing, never managed to fix the issue.
The public folder is empty for some reason, I have a dist folder that has the assets folder containing the images, and index.html, the dist folder appeared when I hosted the react app to GitHub... I don't know if this is informative or not.
One thing I'd like to point out that whenever I make any changes to the code I add all the files again and push them, in the terminal:
git add .

git push -u origin main
//gives an error

npm run deploy

I actually did all the necessary steps when I first deployed the react app, I just do these again to make sure that any changes I commit gets updated in GitHub.
What could be the issue? Please help me fix it, it has been almost a week and I still did not properly host my first react app.

I've cloned your repository (which you should have linked), and was able to deploy it to GitHub pages:

For gh-pages npm run deploy method:

remove the unnecessary directory nesting that you have in the repository; your entire project that you are pushing to GitHub is inside of a directory fitness which will make it harder for you to deploy the app since some tools may struggle to find the dist build output without proper configuration.
Install gh-pages package since you seem to be trying to use it for deployments but it's not actually part of your package.json.
Run npm run deploy

You seem to have also setup a deploy.yml GitHub actions workflow, but it is broken due to credential errors. Your template is different from the one shown on the official vite documentation, which I've used and has worked for me although I had to change some repository settings to undo the configuration done by gh-pages. Pick one way to deploy and stick with it otherwise they will be conflicting with each other.
The deployment is not perfect and it seems that your routing is not playing nicely with GitHub pages. I tried to set the vite configuration base to /{repo_name}/ as instructed in the vite docs, but it doesn't work: If I refresh the page, it goes into 404. I suspect the root page of your routing implementation is interfering with GitHub trying to set the root as the name of the repository, but I'm sure you can figure that part out as you are more familiar with your project and needs.
